# "got X confused with Y" versus "confused X with Y"

Tags: word-order, sentence-patterns

I am really confused which of the following sentences is correct

> - Maybe they got *thin* confused with *short*.
> - Maybe they confused *thin* with *short*.

If both are correct which one would be more appropriate?

Comment: You seem to be using invisible ink. // They're both acceptable, your first variant being probably in a less formal register, at least in the UK. But it would be better to highlight the word-as-a-word usages using quotes or italics: Maybe they confused _thin_ with _short_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the second version would be better in a spoken context, since the italics or quotes would not be apparent. *got thin* sounds like they lost weight, and the listener would have to backtrack and reinterpret it when they hear the rest of the sentence.

In written format, either would be acceptable, so long as you properly indicate that you're mentioning *thin* and *short* rather than using them as adjectives, either by quoting or italicizing them. I think *got* tends to be used less in formal settings, but I don't think it would be a major problem.